# Replacement of Selenium with java functions get() and getAttribute() in Selenium with C#

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was doing automation in Selenium with java and new to C# with selenium. Please suggest how I can use the below java logic in C# visual studio-

```
Int count= driver.findelements(By.Name("radiobutton")).size();

For(int i=0;i< count;i++)

{

String radiobuttonname =driver.findelements(By.Name("radiobutton")).get(i).getAttribute("value");


If(radiobuttonname.equals("radio3"))
{
driver.findelements(By.Name(radiobutton)).get(i).click();
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you look at the docs for C# Selenium, you will generally find it to be nearly exactly the same as Java except for capitalization... `.findElements()` vs `.FindElements()`. Post your code attempts and explain any errors you haven't been able to solve yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is how I might have done it in my selenium project.

```
public static void ClickRadioButton()
{
    var count = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.Name("radiobutton"));
    foreach(var item in count) 
    {
        string radioButtonName = item.Text; //or TagName or what you want.
        if(radioButtonName == "radio3")
        {
            item.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I have a class called `Driver` and a field in that class: `public static IWebDriver Instance {get;set;}` when `Initilized()` (this is a method in the `Driver` class) equals to `new ChromeDriver()`. You can therefore replace `Driver.Instance` with your `driver`.

Start with this and experiment how to move forward and do it your way (you dont have to make a class out of driver if you don't want to for example).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer it is really helpful